# Where can I find CheckList in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to work with List Box that holds check list for each item.But I can't find it in VS2010
Do I need create by handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this standard one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d58s8sak%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

MSDN is right place to start your search from.

Comment: What you don't understand exactly?

Comment: I'm glad for you. Good luck! PS For very complicated UI you can try BCGSoft Controls Pro library.

Comment: Excuse me do u know how bind edit control to spin button control in MFC?)

Comment: Hm, you want [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8z1ck76(v=vs.100).aspx)?